# How do websites identify android devices

Tags: android, flash, browser

I would like to know by what means a website may identify an Android/mobile device. I experience that some websites identify my Android 4.1 device even though I change the User Agent String of the android default browser (by typing `about:debug` in the address bar and changing the corresponding option in the settings menu subsequently). The sites in question contain flash. Do they possibly identify the version of the flash player?

Comment: Figured out that the browser only needed to be reloaded after the User Agent String was changed. So the question is answered for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. most common method is to check the userAgent. im not sure about the flashplayer version but it can identify the mobile device from the screen resolution(screen size)

Comment: I can exclude the screen resolution. The device in question is actually a TV HDMI-stick with HD resolution.